# Вопрос по реализации MVVM.

Tags: c#, gui, проектирование, wpf, mvvm

[image]

Пример заскринил с видео. Не суть.
Это кусок кода из фалйа CustomerViewModel. Customer наша модель. Вопрос - С какой целью создавать _Customer и Customer, ведь мы сами устанавливаем, что делают наши геттеры и сеттеры

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, этот же код можно написать так:

```
public Customer Customer { get; private set; }
```

Разница могла бы появиться в случае, если бы getter делал что-то большее, чем просто возврат переменной.

---

На самом деле, в реальности если мы пишем автоматически определённые свойства, компилятор неявно создаёт поле для нас. В вашем примере это поле было определено явно, что, по моему мнению, избыточно.